# type error : dappcord.totalchannels is not a function

Tags: javascript, testing, blockchain, solidity

hay iam doing blockchain development and currently start  my journey and sometime i get error of these type

`` function createChannel(string memory _name, uint256 _cost)
public
onlyOwner
{
totalChannels++;
channels[totalChannels] = channel(totalChannels, _name, _cost);
}

here is the test file code of create channel funtions

```
   `` describe("Creating Channels", () => {
        it('Returns total channels', async () => {
          const result = await dappcord.totalChannels()
          expect(result).to.be.equal(1)
        })
    
        it('Returns channel attributes', async () => {
          const  channel = await dappcord.getChannel(1)
          expect(channel.id).to.be.equal(1)
          expect(channel.name).to.be.equal("general")
          expect(channel.cost).to.be.equal(tokens(1))
        })
      })
    })`
`
```

in this test file error is showing smart contract is uploaded can anyone solve this

after running test file error showing type error dappcord.totalchannels is not funtion

solve my problem

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the `totalChannels` function or property in your Solidity contract?